# Restricted Download from the market

Tags: android, google-play

I've developed an application for a company and it would be easier to install if i upload it on the market. But, what i would need to do, is set a password, code or whatever, which set a restriction about who is able to download and install the app. Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You cannot** deploy your app with a password using the Market. Try to add authentication on app startup to achieve this.

Here is more information about [Market filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html). This will let you **target a region** or a specific version / language.

You can also implement [application licenses](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html). This will let you make a free/paid app in 1.

If you really want to target a specific group, try **manually deploying** your application via a server / email.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the replies. I was afraid i couldn't. I'm already getting the apk through webservice with password to get updates, but with this i'd avoid a few steps during the installation, because now, they need to get an AppInstaller or use the SDK.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid not. Just use email or any other web server

Answer (score 2):

You can specify some restrictions (Android version, region, etc.) but I don't believe you can limit it to an arbitrary group - You might find it easier to simply publih the APK somewhere on an intranet (assuming the phones connect to the intranet) or on the internet with a username/password and give the URL to the desired users

Answer (score 1):

No, either add a login to authenticate the user or use another way of installing it (email, webpage etc) just make sure that all phones allow unknown sources (under application in settings)